# localStorage is not defined - using angular universal and I have a function that makes use of localStorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, angular, angular-universal

I have a function that I am using in my app, and one of the parameters for the function is an object:

```
const checkValues = {
  promoId: ...,
  ...
  unsaved: !JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('unsaved')) ? [] : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('unsaved'))
}
```

However, the only error I am receiving when I serve up my project is this:

> ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
>       at Object. (/home/meow/Development/dmc/cli_universal/dist/server.bundle.js:4145:23)
>       at **webpack_require** (/home/meow/Development/dmc/cli_universal/dist/server.bundle.js:21:30)
>       at Object. (/home/meow/Development/dmc/cli_universal/dist/server.bundle.js:4119:67)
>       at **webpack_require** (/home/meow/Development/dmc/cli_universal/dist/server.bundle.js:21:30)
>       at Object. (/home/meow/Development/dmc/cli_universal/dist/server.bundle.js:1728:69)
>       at **webpack_require** (/home/meow/Development/dmc/cli_universal/dist/server.bundle.js:21:30)
>       at Object. (/home/meow/Development/dmc/cli_universal/dist/server.bundle.js:1803:70)
>       at **webpack_require** (/home/meow/Development/dmc/cli_universal/dist/server.bundle.js:21:30)
>       at Object. (/home/meow/Development/dmc/cli_universal/dist/server.bundle.js:1509:79)
>       at **webpack_require** (/home/meow/Development/dmc/cli_universal/dist/server.bundle.js:21:30)

How can I check if localStorage exists?

Comment: Did you try `window.localStorage`?

Comment: No I did not.  So would it be just window.localStorage.getItem?

Comment: If you're executing this on the server, `localStorage` won't exist (and neither will `window`).

Answer (score 6):

localstorage is a browser component and you are trying to use that on server side, you will have to make sure that you are calling localstorage when you are on browser side only.

For that you can use angular isPlatformBrowser module.

example

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';  
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any) {}
ngOnInit() {
  if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
    this.id = localStorage.getItem('id');
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation for the [Universal Starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) you'll the following section (as part of the Gotcha's):

> window, document, navigator, and other browser types - do not exist on
>   the server - so using them, or any library that uses them (jQuery for
>   example) will not work.

I suppose that's why you're getting this error.

Comment: No. If I understand correctly, the Universal Starter is used for server side rendering. There is no localStorage equivalent on the server.

Comment: darn okay.  i guess i will try the isNode isBrowser thing and see if that works

Answer (score -2):

$scope.$watch  Should resolve your issues, Ideally when you are trying to invoke a function which is outside of scop, you need to add $watch to get it rendered on to it.

Comment: That is AngularJS syntax, NOT Angular 2 as the asker is referring to.